# My domain name changes to an IP address in the URL bar when visited. How can I fix this?

Tags: domains, vps

I have a domain name, that points to the address of my VPS. And when I visit the website the URL changes to the IP address of the VPS I own. I would like it to keep the URL as the domain name. How do I configure this?

Comment: Is your VPS running Apache, or some other web server?

Comment: It is running Apache.

Answer (score 2):

```
<HTML> <HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; url=http://192.184.88.89/">  </HEAD> </HTML>
```

You need to remove this.

Looks like you have done URL forwarding via domain panel.

Comment: I am forwarding by domain panel, whats the correct way to link my domian name to the content on my VPS?

Comment: Point the nameservers at your domain registrar to those of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is performing a meta refresh to the content at the IP address. If you don't have hosting at the same place you registered your domain name then I assume you need to find out the correct nameservers to use and remove the meta refresh.